# Python-quote a string in Python with proper escapes

Tags: python-3.x, string, escaping, quotes

I want to take a string, and return the Python-style quoted representation of this string. How can I do this correctly, ie. respecting Python syntax?

Some examples of what I want:

- `cat` -> `"cat"`
- `"dog"` -> `'"dog"'`
- `'elephant'` -> `"'elephant'"`
- `"what's up"` -> `'"what\'s up "'`
- `'''"""seriously dude?"""'''` -> `'\'\'\'"""seriously dude?"""\'\'\'`

Note that quotes are correctly escaped, which is more complex than simply doing `f'"{s}"'` like recommended in some similar questions.

I know that there can be multiple ways to represent the same string in Python (`"cat"`, `'cat'`, `"""cat"""`, `"c"'a'"t"`, ...). I don't have a preference as to which one is used, just so long as the result would parse in Python as a valid string literal.

For context: My Python program generates Python code. Part of user input is some raw strings, which must be transformed into quoted Python literals in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a Python specific way to do this, but coincidentally JSON has similar string literal syntax:

```
def quote_string(s: str) -> str:
    # JSON string literals are a subset of Python (?)
    return json.dumps(s)
```

- I'm not sure if this is always correct - I think some escape sequences may be valid in Python and not in JSON or vice versa
- JSON doesn't have the many quote flavors, so it can't efficiently utilize some optimizations like `'no "big" deal'` instead of `"no \"big\" deal"`

There's probably a better way than this, but I can't think of one.